# Use jQuery $.each() to iterate through object

Tags: jquery, object, each

Trying to iterate through and get key/value values from the following object:

```
var schedules = {
    "0": {
        "STAGE1": "1/2/13",
        "STAGE2": "2/12/13"
    },
    "1": {
        "STAGE1": "2/4/13",
        "STAGE2": "3/9/13"
    }
    "2": {
        "STAGE1": "4/13/13",
        "STAGE2": "5/21/13"
    }
}
```

with the following jQuery:

```
$.each(schedules, function(index) {

    $.each(schedules[index], function(key, value) {
        $("ul#list").append("<li>" + key + " " + value + "</li>");
    });

});
```

so that I end up with a simple list:

- STAGE1 1/2/13
- STAGE2 2/12/13
- STAGE1 2/4/13
- STAGE2 3/9/13
- STAGE1 4/13/13
- STAGE2 5/21/13

I don't seem to be using $.each() correctly... what am i doing wrong? Thx!

Comment: Why don't you use an array?

Comment: It's a data structure that I'm being given so I don't have an option to change it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ3M3/

Comment: Thanks megawac! Works great too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple syntax error: http://jsfiddle.net/46bv5/

```
"1": {
    "STAGE1": "2/4/13",
    "STAGE2": "3/9/13"
}, //need a comma here
"2": {
    "STAGE1": "4/13/13",
    "STAGE2": "5/21/13"
}
```

Be sure to check your error console when something isn't working.

Comment: Thanks. Although that was just an input error on my part when I typed it in. The object is built correctly since it's being JSON encoded from another data source and I can access the individual elements using schedules[0].STAGE1 for example. i just can't seem to auto iterate through them.

Comment: Did you check my fiddle? It appears to be working as you said it should.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma:

```
"1": {
    "STAGE1": "2/4/13",
    "STAGE2": "3/9/13"
}, // HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

yes there was syntax error please put a comma before "2"

```
"1": {
    "STAGE1": "2/4/13",
    "STAGE2": "3/9/13"
}, //here you have missed comma
"2": {
```

Answer (score 0):

Always validate your JSON schema from JSON formatter online to check your JSON arrays:

Looks like you were missing Comma. Expecting comma or }, not string.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#